# Flutter: Material Widget And SingleChildScrollView Render Conflict Inside Drawer

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, singlechildscrollview, ripple-effect, expansion-tile

This problem only happens inside Drawer

I wanted to shape the ripple effect of my ExpansionTile so I used the Material widget and it works, but when the tile expands, the background color of the tiles below ExpansionTile does not move with them.

When ExpansionTile is collapsed

[image]

When ExpansionTile is expanded

[image]

I found out that when I remove SingleChildScrollView the problem solves but I need items to scroll. Also when ScrollPhysics has been set to AlwaysScroll, scrolling till the end of the scroll's possible position would rerender items and fix the issue.

Reproducible Example:

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Title',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Title'),
        ),
        drawer: const MyList(),
        body: Container(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyList extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            items(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget items() {
    return Wrap(
      runSpacing: 12,
      children: [
        menu(),
        const ListTile(title: Text('title'), tileColor: Colors.grey),
        const ListTile(title: Text('title')),
      ]
    );
  }

  Widget menu() {
    return Material(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      type: MaterialType.transparency,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
      ),
      child: const ExpansionTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.group),
        title: Text('title'),
        children: [
          ListTile(title: Text('title')),
          ListTile(title: Text('title')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample full widget that will reproduce the same error ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I updated my example codes to be reproducive.

Comment: You can try Miro methods, btw is there any specific reason using Wrap

Comment: @YeasinSheikh it didn't work. seems the problem is with scrollability. I used Wrap for spacing between items but I also tried Column instead of Wrap and the same problem happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked for this problem on flutter's Github repo and I got the answer.
Just need to use ListTileTheme widget instead of Material widget.

Github issue link:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/112372

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid SingleChildScrollView and still be able to scroll over a list, you can use ListView.builder link: - [ListView.builder flutter.dev](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists)

Comment: It didn't work still had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `type: MaterialType.transparency,`

```dart
class MyList extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) items(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget items() {
    return Wrap(
      children: [
        menu(),
        const ListTile(
          title: Text('title'),
          tileColor: Colors.grey,
        ),
        const ListTile(title: Text('title')),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget menu() {
    return Material(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
      // type: MaterialType.transparency,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
      child: const ExpansionTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.group),
        title: Text('title'),
        children: [
          ListTile(title: Text('title')),
          ListTile(title: Text('title')),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Same thing happens, just the colored tile's paint will get hidden under the Material Widget's paint

Comment: Seems like I missed the actual being custom theme,